# how to relate the model and use it

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have four models: shop(user), product, customer, and order.
 How I can relate that on home page shop gets its  customer and order

**shop**

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True,related_name='shop', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=70, serialize=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=70)`
```

**product**

```
Shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, serialize=True)
Brand = models.CharField(max_length=200)`
```

**customer**

```
Shop = models.ManyToManyField(Shop)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, serialize=True)
Phone = models.FloatField()`
```

**order**

```
Shop = models.ManyToManyField(Shop)
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
product = models.ManyToManyField(Products)`
```

Answer (score 0):

if your queryset is as follows you can display it as shown in templates

```
shops=Shop.objects.all() 

{% for shop in shops %}
    {{ shop.name }}
{% for customer in shop.customer.all %}{{ customer }}{% endfor %}
{% for order in shop.order.all %}{{ order }}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```